# How to pull in the typescript hints for a function's argument documentation

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, visual-studio-code

if I create some Express.js middleware, how can I have my editor (VSCode) provide the typescript hints as if I referenced the library directly?

For example, what can I put in the `@param` section to get the Express.js hints?

**file.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

/**
 * 
 * @param {Express.Request} req 
 * @param {Express.Response} res 
 */
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if (true) {
        res.json(true); // ** when I hover over `json` no hints are shown **
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

app.use(myMiddleware);
```

I would like to hover over `res`, for example, and see what methods/properties it includes.

Answer (score 0):

> function's argument documentation

Your question is really "How to get TypeScript to use JSDoc *type* annotation" e.g. you want the types to get picked up for:

```
/**
 *  @param {Express.Request} req
 *  @param {Express.Response} res
 */
function myMiddleware(req, res) { ... }
```

## Solution

Use `.js` file extension (type annotation in jsdoc are not picked up for ts files) and use `allowJs: true` in your tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';

/**
 * My middleware
 * @param {Request} req Express Request...
 * @param {Response} res Express Response...
 */
function middleware(req : Request, res : Response){
    res.send('Hello!'); //You will get hints when using the parameters
}

middleware(req /* You will get hints when passing the parameters */, res);
```